# Is there an event or property on the window that shows when network calls are being made or have completed?

Tags: javascript, networking, browser

Is there a property on the window object or document that indicates if a network call is being made?

I have this code all over my pages that displays an icon when a network call is made:

```
  showNetworkIcon();
  var response = await fetch(url);
  var data = await response.json();
  showNetworkIcon(false);
```

But if there are two calls at once then one of them will hide the network call indicator while there are still network calls happening.

Is there a property like this:

```
var networkCall = window.requestsOpen;
```

Then I can not hide the network icon if that value is true.

Or if there is an event I can listen for:

```
window.addEventListener("networkCallOpen", ()=>{ showNetworkIcon() });
window.addEventListener("networkCallClosed", ()=>{ hideNetworkIcon() });
```

The problem with the above is that if two calls are still one will close before the other so there still needs to be a property to check. Unless there was a an all calls closed event.

```
window.addEventListener("allNetworkCallsClosed", ()=>{ hideNetworkIcon() });
```

Comment: there's no event, afaik. You can wrap `fetch()` (or stomp on it if you don't want to mod existing code) to run init/teardown code each time it's used. You still would have the race condition though. Instead of just hiding when done, see if there's remaining calls and do nothing if so. The simple way to do that is to increment a counter on fetch() and decrement on then() (or after await) and only when the counter is zero do you hide your icon. All you need to change is showNetworkIcon() to keep a counter.

Comment: @dandavis thats a good idea. i'm trying to get a one line fetch and i could handle the icon issue at the same time

Comment: Side-question: do you want the icon to go away when _all_ requests are done or when the _last one made_ is complete. Remember that requests can finish out of order and there are use cases where you want to ignore all requests except the last one (e.g. two autocomplete requests fired when user typed 3 and 4 characters, you'll want to hide the icon when the 4 character XHR is complete).

Comment: @SalmanA good question. I want to turn off the icon when ALL requests are done. If they are out of order that is ok.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr - no :(

Inside a service worker there's the [FetchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent).  In a normal window we just have [Abort Signal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) to natively interact with a fetch

You could wrap your [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in a function that would [emit an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) before and after.  Here's a function I'm using in a project where I've added in some events.  Hopefully it gets you pointed in the right direction as it doesn't all the requirements in your question.

```
    fetch: function(url, method = 'GET', data = null) {
        const event = new CustomEvent("networkCallOpen", { detail: url });
        window.document.dispatchEvent(event);

        const init = {
            method: method,
            headers: Auth.authHeader()
        };

        if(data && method !== 'GET') {
            init.body = JSON.stringify(data);
        }

        return fetch(ApiConfig.apiUrl(url), init)
               .then(() => {
                    const event = new CustomEvent("networkCallClosed", , { detail: url });
                    window.document.dispatchEvent(event);
                })            
                .then((resp) => checkResponse(resp, method))
                .then(buildResponse);
    }
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go for now. thanks

Comment: The promise returned by `fetch()` is fulfilled once the response is available, but it doesn't mean that the response body is completely fetched nor that the network call is closed, only that the response headers are available. If you try this code in a browser console with the network tab open, you will see that the networkCallClosed event is fired before the "content download" part is finished (to make things more obvious try with a large image file). Also the first .then() doesn't return any response so `resp` is undefined in the 2nd .then().

Comment: @EricLavault you're correct. you could emit after something like `response.json().  there's a lot of missing code that goes with the example above.  the code was a 'point them in the right direction'.  the full code has a function called 'checkResponse' where i check and do stuff based on return code and fetch method.